# wget temporary failure in name resolution + unable to resolve host address

Tags: curl, ubuntu-16.04, wget, large-files

I am trying to download few datasets, in the website the download command is given as below:

```
sudo wget -v --report-speed=bits -o log --progres=dot --continue --timestamping "https://ni...."
```

There is also a download button, I can download the dataset using a browser (the download starts), but it's too large so I need to download the dataset to a server using the `wget` command.

When I run `wget` command in the server, the download never starts and I get the following errors in the log:
`cat log`

```
user@anonymous_serv29GQ-TVRT:~/Data/AUDIO_DATA$ cat log
The name is too long, 1443 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is cts*******Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210917T165701Z&X-Amz-Expires=180&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3asassasJpZ2luX2V*******.
--2021-09-17 23:32:27--  https://ni****?X-Amz-Algorithm*******75d22ccfc6
Resolving nis**.s3.amazonaws.com (n***.amazonaws.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ni****.s3.amazonaws.com’
```

I tried using the browser dev tool and copy as curl, but it failed too. Another option I see is by installing vnc in the server and using a browser, but it is still not a complete solution as I need to make sure the download continues even if I quit my session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a DNS problem in my server. I edited the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

[image]

Finally, used this command to download

```
wget -c -O "out.tar.gz" "URL"
```